# .htaccess rewrite folder to subdomain Error

Tags: php, regex, apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have some stuck. 
I was config
Apache

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
      ServerAdmin webmaster@example.com
      DocumentRoot /home/abc/Projects/
      ServerAlias *.example.com
      ServerName example.com
      ErrorLog error.log
</VirtualHost>
```

my **.htaccess** file

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ /%1/$1 [QSA,L]
```

my webpage was return **Internal Server Error**

How I can config **.htaccess** accept to

> - query: **http://test.example.com**
> - It mean: **http://example.com/test/**
> - **test** is a folder into root web dir.

**update** My Error Log

[Sat Aug 22 21:29:58.093791 2015] [core:error] [pid 31081] [client 192.168.83.1:7322] AH00124: Request exceeded the limit of 10 internal redirects due to probable configuration error. Use 'LimitInternalRecursion' to increase the limit if necessary. Use 'LogLevel debug' to get a backtrace., referer: http://test.example.com/

**Apache/2.4.10 (Ubuntu) Server at test.example.com Port 80**

**thk's any got a tip**

Comment: "Internal error" means: look into the `error.log`. There's a more specific reason on why it failed. (Disabled mod_rewrite or RewriteEngine or AllowOverride etc. etc. etc.)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You rule is infinitely looping and eventually causing 500 error. To stop that you can use this additional condition:

```
RewriteCond %{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS} ^$
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(.+)\.example\.com$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ %1/$1 [L]
```

`%{ENV:REDIRECT_STATUS}` is an internal `mod_rewrite` variable that is set to 200 after first internal rewrite.